# Не правильно указывает путь к файлу на API 29(java)

Tags: java, android

пытаюсь подцепить файл с помощью Intent'а, но почему-то обнаружил, что на некоторых устройствах(с API 29) путь к файлу не правилен(в результате имя файла в пути к нему, заменяется цифрами), а вот на API ниже все хорошо цепляется. Как это можно исправить?
Вот мой код:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Global_variable.Uri_for_picker = data.getData();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

  private final View.OnClickListener onClickListenerLoader = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Тест выбора файла
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете в этом случае получить путь к файлу посредством следующего "костыля":

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    Global_variable.Uri_for_picker = getDataColumn(this, uri, null, null);
}
....
....
public String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```